# Can std::initializer_list be specialized?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, initializer-list

While going through the various rules on list-initialization, I found this in [dcl.init.list#3.6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.6):

> Otherwise, if T is a specialization of `std​::​initializer_­list<E>`, the object is constructed as described below.

On the other hand, in the synopsis of `std::initializer_list`, in [support.initlist](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.initlist#initializer.list.syn-2), I found the following statement:

> If an explicit specialization or partial specialization of `initializer_­list` is declared, the program is ill-formed.

These *appear* to be contradictory statements, so what am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"A template specialization" has two distinct meanings:

1. "Explicit (full) specialization" or "partial specialization" - a language construct that changes the meaning of a template for some combination of template parameters.
2. Something that was generated from a template by substituting template arguments into it.
   In other words, if you specify template arguments for a template, the resulting type/function/variable/... is a *specialization* of that template. E.g. `std::vector<int>` is a *specialization* of `std::vector`.

Looks like the first passage you quote uses (2).

So *"if `T` is a specialization of `std​::​initializer_­list<E>`"* roughly means "if there exists such `E` that `std::is_same_v<T, std::initializer_list<E>>`", or "if `T` **is** a `std::initializer_list<E>`".

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. "if there exists ...", but that specialization that exists must be generated by the compiler, and not the user?

Comment: @cigien No, by "exists" I didn't mean "instantianted" or anything like that. What I was trying to say is "if `T` **is** `std::initializer_list<E>` (for some E)".

Comment: @cigien Edited for clarity (hopefully).

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. I feel the standard wording could be less confusing here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction.

> If an explicit specialization or partial specialization of initializer_­list is declared, the program is ill-formed.

Means you cannot declare a specialization.  The compiler itself is allowed to stamp out specializations of `std​::​initializer_­list`

---

The thing that might be causing you issue is that the concrete type you get out of a template is called a specialization.  This is what the first paragraph is talking about.  The second paragraph is talking about actually defining/declaring a specialization for `std::initializer_list`

Comment: Aah, so the `initializer_list<E>` mentioned above is generated by the compiler, but a user can't do that? I'm not sure what it means to specialize `initializer_list<E>` then. What's to specialize?

Comment: @cigien Correct.  You can't define a `template <> std::initializer_list<my_type>`, but you can declare a `std::initializer_list<some_type>` and the compiler will stamp out a specialization of `std::initiliazer_list` for `some_type`.